# Windows 7 Proper search syntax for exact and only exact match

Tags: windows-7, search, file-filter

In Windows 7 if I search for `"debug"` I would expect only files and folders that are EXACTLY `debug`. Which would only be extension-less files named debug, or folders.

Windows being it's ever ready "helpful" expands my results to return things like `_debug` or `jquery.debug.js`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the search filters with an equal sign to force the exact match.

So searching for `debug` returns everything with 'debug' in any searchable meta-data,

searching for `Name:debug` returns everything with 'debug' in the name,

and searching with `Name:=debug` returns only the entries that are named exactly 'debug'.

Comment: I found having to do name: beyond incredibly stupid, doing just =Debug behaves as "debug" should.

Comment: Yeah I often think it should assume the "name" metadata, but how would you search 'all' metadata then? ;)

Comment: the obvious answer is it should require "All:" since that's the strange case, so I should assume that running =debug is actually hitting the other meta values that maybe I will actually want to use the name: syntax sigh.